# How should I handle a senior colleague who speaks disparagingly?

Tags: relationships, seniority

I've got a senior colleague, whom I can't get along with too well.

We've had some bad interactions when I just joined the company, because he just throws everything he thinks out in the wild, without thinking about the impact that it might have on somebody.

I responded to that in a defensive way and since then, our interaction is different, than the interactions he has with other colleague.

When discussing work related things he just acts normal, but whenever I shine something through to my other colleagues about things I'm doing in my private time, he immediately picks it up and starts to comment in a disparaging manner. I get that some people might want the conversation to end and that stands in their full right. However, this person does not ask for the conversation to end, but starts joking negatively about the things that I'm talking about.

He quite often joins the out of work conversations of other colleagues and is happy to involve in those conversations, but whenever he is involved in my conversations he places negative jokes into the conversation.

I find it annoying that whenever I'm showing what I've accomplished or the next thing that I need to accomplish, non work-related, that he's so negative and disparaging.

Sometimes it goes through my mind, that he might have influence on the career path that I'm working on, since he is a senior after all.

I am quite sensitive to social outings, such as these.

How should I handle this?
I've tried to ignore it, but unfortunately it does have an impact on me. Should I take him aside (non-aggressive way of asking, why he said something negative) the next time he says something disparaging, and ask him what that was about?

I want our relationship to be normal, as with any other colleagues.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150658/discussion-on-question-by-generaloctopusnl-how-should-i-handle-a-senior-colleagu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 26):

First off: I think you meant to write "*take him aside*" instead of "*take him apart*" given the context of the rest of the sentence? If so, that would greatly change the tone of your question.

I genuinely don't understand why you are getting so much negative feedback here. Why is everyone acting like it isn't completely normal and healthy to have a relationship with your coworkers where you can discuss activities you do outside of work? And why is everyone seemingly on the side of the guy who is constantly disparaging and belittling you and only you for it, when he isn't even the person you're talking to? Especially someone senior to you. I would be going straight to HR if this happened more than once to me. Maybe my workplaces have been different from what other people have experienced, but that is bizarre to me.

What they are saying that **is** valid is that you should probably take a step back and examine your own behavior. You stated that you responded defensively to him early on - is it possible that you are more consistently defensive and closed off to his criticism than your coworkers? He is your senior, so if you are that could be contributing to your poor relationship. And it is not out of the question that your enthusiasm about your interests does manifest itself in a "braggy" way, which does not excuse his behavior but is something you should work on. That being said, IMO it is ridiculous for people here to **assume** that you are being braggy and blame your problem on that. It may be worth asking a couple of your coworkers if they think that's how you come across.

Now, for your actual question as to how to handle this: I would start by toning down how much you talk about your interests when you are near this coworker. It's the easiest way for you to reduce the friction short term. Also, start documenting exactly what is said any time he does make negative comments to you, so you can A) build a case and B) maybe you'll find that it actually doesn't happen as frequently or what he says isn't as negative as you think. I wouldn't confront him about this issue, that's a job for HR if you eventually get them involved. Finally, be honest with yourself about whether you are treating him with enough respect in the first place. He is a senior, so a certain level of respect within the workplace is warranted. Make sure you are not acting as the antagonizer in his story.

Comment: If I was at my table trying to code and there was someone talking about how their dog won a competition, it would be an instant "Will you shut up please ? I'm trying to actually work here", because I need silence to work, and if your talking loud enough that a pair or headphones. It's not talking about hobbies in the workplace, it's talking about them in the middle of where you are supposed to work. Cafeterias, breaking rooms, whatever he might have, are the correct place for these types of conversations, Not in the middle of what sound to me to be an open space office.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t nothing in the original question specifically indicates that the asker is chit-chatting at inappropriate times, and nothing about the senior colleague indicates that they're being negative because they're being interrupted - in fact it reads like the timing and content of these conversations are perfectly reasonable for their workplace. As InBedded16 says in this answer, it's a bit ridiculous to assume the worst when there's no concrete evidence for it.

Comment: @jla the OP didn't in any way specify they were talking somewhere away from desks, and that's the only way I can understand the senior behavior. It's a bit ridiculous to assume the best scenario without any concrete evidence for it. OP should just keep his out of work conversation, Out of work, that way he would save both his fragile feelings and ego. Not everyone likes cars, or people who only talk about cars all the time. The senior might really just not like him, it's not impossible, yet OP is oblivious to it.

Comment: @jla Also clearly the OP is bragging, before the edit, he said that the senior was jealous. IMO, it's quite clear OP has an inflated ego and thinks everyone is as excited about his personal projects as himself, some people just don't care, some people just hate people being overly enthusiastic about such trivial events, I know because I do. HR is not going to prevent me from commenting on other people's conversations. So people just don't talk about their "Achievements" near me, its a win win situation that OP just can't see.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t The assumptions you're making about the OP here, and the absolute confidence with which you've made them, are frankly bizarre. I would respectfully suggest that you should question whether they are well-founded on things the OP has directly described, or whether they are patterns of behavior that you dislike in your own workplace and have imputed to the OP as a matter of speculation.

Comment: @Sneftel defenitly there's some projection on my part, I don't have anyone in my workplace like that, but I have been on both ends of the same situation multiples times. Enough to know that someone who says others are jealous of them because they don't have a "Special" car, is pretentious and braggy about it. You seem to be ignoring the fact that OP said the senior was jealous of him because of his car, and him going to the gym, because the senior doesnt live life the same way he does.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t And maybe they *are* jealous! Or maybe they aren't, but why *start* by assuming the OP's apprehension of the situation is flat-out wrong? If they're delusional about the problem then they'll be delusional about whether the 'right' solution applies to them. As a matter of practicality we're sort of forced to take them at their word.

Comment: @Sneftel ill agree with you on the practicality of it, doesn't mean I'm comfortable contributing to someone's delusion, ill just leave this as it is since I don't want another ban.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t thanks for mentioning the edit. This "I've got the feeling that he's quite jealous. I've got a special car, I'm working on my own business ideas, I've got a YouTube channel, I'm going to the gym everyday. He has got none of that" makes me see the OP in a different light

Comment: *"And why is everyone seemingly on the side of the guy who is constantly disparaging and belittling you and only you for it, when he isn't even the person you're talking to?"* <<< That's actually a pretty common bullying tactic. If person A acts very nice and friendly with everyone except B, and bullies B, it can become very hard for B to be taken seriously when they complain. Whenever B is going to claim that A was nasty, B is going to be met with "Come on, you must be misinterpreting A's words, A is very nice and would never do that".

Comment: @Stef by "everyone" I was referring to people on this site, responding to this question, not OP's coworkers. But that is good insight.

Comment: @AaronF it really shouldn't. You're making an assumption about OP by a single sentence they wrote, a sentence which is simply trying to give us context for why they think this coworker is being negative towards them. You have no idea if OP is actually "pretentious and braggy" just from that sentence, and assuming so takes away from the point of the question.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t I don't think other people are as excited about my project/car as I am, but I do assume that seniors have a level of seniority, which means that if I talk about other projects, with another collegues, that he must respect that. I'm not saying he should like the project, but he must at least respect it. I think because some nuances are missing, because English is not my first language, you're assuming that I talk about my car and projects the whole time.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t with my sentence  "I've got the feeling that he's quite jealous. I've got a special car, I'm working on my own business ideas, I've got a YouTube channel, I'm going to the gym everyday. He has got none of that" I was hoping we could figure out if he was trying to pull me down or not, by giving more context. Because again, that wouldn't be very senior of him to do so

Answer (score 5):

He most likely doesn't like you.
Face it, you started off in the wrong foot with him, and kept pressing on the gas by constantly speaking about (insert whatever you talk about) in the workplace.

My advice would be to refrain from touching certain topics (which trigger said behavior), and keeping your relationship strictly professional and respectful, the workplace isn't the place to talk about your private "achievements" IMO.

Take the people you want to talk with for a coffee after work, then you can talk away about any subject you want without negative comments.

OR

Talk to him and ask why he always makes such negative comments about your personal life, and say you are sorry for the comments you made when you first met, most likely he was just trying to banter and you, being the new guy, got defensive. I did that in my first job, had problems with my team leader because I took it too personally and not as a witty playful comment. Bantering was the way to break the ice with my team leader, maybe it is too with your senior.

This will make or break your relationship, either he tells you why, and you can/want to fix it. He might always shrug it off and not give you a reason (which I think is more likely), in that case that's a clear signal of "I don't like you and have no interest talking to you". That's where you stick to my first point and just be professional and respectful.

Personal Opinion:
He is also a senior, that should warrant some respect on your part which you clearly lack when you ask if you should "take him apart the next time he says something disparaging", he has as much right to comment negatively on your hobby as you have to bring it up near him. In all my time working, I've never had a single ounce of interest for other people's hobbies, maybe he just doesn't like the typical "car guy", and sees you as one, who knows if he tries to deter you from talking about X near him, get away.

Comment: *the workplace isn't the place to talk about your private "achievements" IMO* We spend a huge chunk of our lives at work - it is absolutely a place where work tangent or unrelated topics are discussed and this is a normal thing, at least in my culture (French)

Comment: @WoJ So it is in mine (Portugal), doesn't mean that I personally need to abide by it or enjoy it, I keep things to myself and force others to do the same around me. Not once has anyone been offended, I've been called anti-social, which I guess I am. That doesn't give everybody else the right to make me miserable, and vice versa.

Comment: *That doesn't give everybody else the right to make me miserable, and vice versa* OF COURSE not. What I meant is not that everyone should discuss of personal stuff at the office, I was referring to your statement that the workplace is not the place to do so. Everyone is free to speak or not speak. BTW I have a very diverse team with all extremes and they live together extremely well because everyone behaves the way they want without any pressure (on them or others).

Comment: @WoJ Seems like a dream environment, keep up the great work

Answer (score 1):

> I find it annoying that whenever I'm showing what I've accomplished or the next thing that I need to accomplish, non work-related, that he's so negative and disparaging.

This is workplace, your coworkers are free to not care even one bit about your out of work life. And yet if this continues to come up, and you somehow involve that person in that conversation (for example by having them in the ear shot, instead of doing it at a break room), eventually they may speak up hoping to cut it short.

Them eventually telling you to cut it out is not their fault, you are the one forcing them to hear something they have no interest in.

But honestly, more telling than your question is your tone and the comments, as you seem quite oblivious to how it can come across. You can say "I am not bragging at all!" but 'that's like just your opinion, man' situation and you are in the middle of it, unable to see how it comes through.

> Should I take him apart the next time he says something disparaging, and ask him what's wrong?

This is prime example of what I am trying to say. You ask on how to handle it, how to get along, but at the same time somehow you consider it even as a possibility to go and tear them a new one for being disinterested in your out of work life. They don't have to care, and if they have to keep hearing about it, you can expect backlash, where honestly that backlash may just be casual remarks that disagree with your view, but you take more personally.

Especially after you've done that to them at the start of your relationship, but now dislike the other end of the stick.

> How should I handle this?

Take your out of work chat to the break room. It's simple as that, if you actually want to maintain those good relations.

Think about it as working remotely, having a channel called "project X work discussion" which gets hijacked a lot with chatter that's on entirely unrelated topics and there already exists the channel called "off topic" where that discussion would belong. But because it keeps taking over "project x work discussion", people who may have "off topic" muted now have to deal with the conversation they specifically set out to avoid.

Treat your office in the same manner. Yes, small off topic will happen, but keep it at that - small and sometimes, anything bigger goes to a break room.

Comment: I get that collegues do not care a single bit about my out of work life and everybody has it's rights to request the end of a non-working conversation, but the main point is that he doesn't do that. He starts speaking negative things and starts making negatively loaded jokes, whereas if somebody else talks about his out of work life, he goes along with the conversation without saying something negative once

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL does he just start randomly talking negative things about your personal life, completely out of the blue, or is that after you/someone else brought out the topic?

Comment: The topic was started in one way or another, he doesn't just start talking negative things, but if you don't like to participate in the topic you can just ignore it or ask the conversation to stop, right?

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL Then the answer stands, don't start the topic, don't nurture it, they got nothing to chime in. But as I said, i don't believe your question as honest, you seem very keen on taering them a new one rather than happily coexisting. Which you have the right to do, just be ready for consequences.

Comment: I get your point on not starting a topic, so he got nothing to chime in about, but I believe there must also be another solution.

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL I am sure there is, i personally couldn't be bothered trying to fix whatever is at the root of it (which almost always is a fault on both sides) when there's much simple solution present to resolve it in a guaranteed way. I'm lazily pragmatic lass like that.

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL - So can you provide a practical example of one of these negative jokes? Clearly work appropriate, and an edit to your question

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL Are these conversations of yours the same type as the ones that your coworkers start, e.g. do they regularly share about their outside of work accomplishments too? I’m trying to see if you are being singled out because your behavior is different from your colleagues’ and your senior just objects to your behavior (rudely), or if you are all acting exactly the same and your senior just doesn’t like (or is for some other reason picking on) you. It’s an important difference that we really need you to clarify to fully help.

Comment: (And FWIW I do think coworkers should share about their lives with each other and not just be business all the time, so I don’t agree with the answers/comments that you’re out of line for engaging in personal conversation at work as long as it’s workplace appropriate)

Comment: @bob I don't think anyone said to not speak about hobbies, just to keep it into breakout rooms. Not sure why thjat's such a controversial concept.

Comment: @AidaPaul But that's not what you're saying with your first line: "This is workplace, your coworkers are free to not care even one bit about your out of work life" (even when later you mention "break room", this first sentence occludes it). If "keep it into breakout rooms" is what you meant, perhaps the way the answer is presented can be improved a little.

Comment: @justhalf They don't have to care at all, it's not related. I can politely nod along as I listen about your cats fun weekend, doesn't mean I care, I'm simply being polite in small talk.

Comment: It depends on work culture at your company I guess. Some companies keep all conversations to scheduled breaks in the break room, some have employees come up and talk with one another casually from time to time. So it does depend on company culture where you work.

Comment: @AidaPaul Some people can't pretend to be interested, or unapologetically just banter until they stop with the topic.

Comment: I suspect there is a misunderstanding here. It is very possible that when the OP wrote "take them apart", they meant "take them aside and talk to them privately", not "rip them apart into pieces".

Comment: @Stef yes, English is not my first language and I feel like quite a few assumptions have been made based on some missing nuances in my question.

Comment: @bob well the thing is that I'm having conversations with other collegeages and then he breaks into the conversation and spews negative chatter, which he then tries to justify as a joke

Comment: @GeneralOctopusNL To be clear I’m not defending him, I’m trying to get more information so we can figure out his motivations and better advise you. Right now we don’t know enough to do so.